# C++ String literal and constants

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constants, constexpr

Before asking this, I read [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20944784/436559), but the issue is a bit different.
I'm using this in my class:

```
static constexpr char* kSuffix = "tos";
```

Compiling with gcc with c++11 got me this error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Werror=write-strings]
```

But `constexpr` is a stricter constraint than `const` does, so a `constexpr` is must a `const`, but not vice versa. So I wonder why is gcc not recognising `constexpr` in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [const constexpr char\* vs. constexpr char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561104/const-constexpr-char-vs-constexpr-char)

Comment: Or maybe [constexpr const vs constexpr variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845058/constexpr-const-vs-constexpr-variables) is a closer fit for a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

> so a `constexpr` is must a `const`

Note that the `constexpr` is qualified on `kSuffix` itself, so the pointer becomes `const` (as `char* const`), but the pointee won't become `const` (as `const char*`). Gcc just wants to tell you that you should declare `kSuffix` as a pointer to `const`, i.e.

```
static constexpr const char* kSuffix = "tos";
```

Comment: Is `constexpr` not qualified on `kSuffix`?

Comment: @fluter Yes. I revised the answer, does it become more clear?

Comment: I still wonder why `constexpr` take place of `const` here, they are in the same position essentially.

Comment: @fluter It's better to consider `constexpr` and `const` as different things; e.g. we can declare a `const` pointer like `char* const` and a pointer to `const` like `const char*`, but we can only write `constexpr char*` (or `constexpr const char*`) which means a `constexpr` pointer. (Also note we can't write sth like `char* constexpr`.)