# C++14 How often should I use constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

I've been reading a book about C++14/11. I just finished reading a chapter about the `constexpr` keyword. I know what it's used for, but how often should I use `constexpr`? Should I use it even in code for classes I know will never be used to create `contstexpr` objects? (Just in case, because it doesn't cost me anything, right?)

Comment: You ask for opinions. From my point if view, you should use it as often as you can. Someone might have different thoughts.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Problem is that 'opinions' are off-topic here (_primarily opinion based_ category).

Comment: Early and often. And twice on Sundays.

Comment: @black That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: I know this is not the time nor place, but let me just say: I find it dumb that this site considers it off-topic to ask for opinions (even opinions like this), because, why wouldn't i want to hear an opinion of someone who is much better and more experienced than me?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis _"Opinions aren't off-topic"_ Huh?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Of course every answer is subjective - humans can't reason otherwise. But there is at least a _minimum_ of objectiveness at the bottom: _facts_ rather than _opinions_. Here I wouldn't know how to write an answer. It is _way_ too dependent on OP's code, something we can't control.

Comment: IOW, how would you say flatmouse's answer is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> C++14 How often should I use constexpr?

There's an extensive discussion in item 15 (*Use constexpr whenever possible*) of the [Scott Meyer's](http://www.aristeia.com/contactinfo.html) book [Effective Modern C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html).

The outline of this item is that `constexpr` should be used whenever possible, due to the fact that `constexpr` functions and objects can be used in a wider range of contexts than the non-`constexpr` ones.

However, in the same item the author mentions a caveat of overusing `constexpr`. That is, if you decide to qualify an object or a function as `constexpr` your clients will be allowed to use it in `constexpr` contents. However, if you later decide that this code must not be `constexpr` and remove `constexpr`, this can cause your code not to compile including the side effects that this will have to your clients.

Quoting from original text:

> *“Use constexpr whenever possible” is your willingness to make a long-term commitment to the constraints it imposes on the objects and
>   functions you apply it to.*

Answer (score 1):

[Google's C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Use_of_constexpr) suggests:

> Use constexpr to specify true constants and the functions that support their definitions. consteval may be used for code that must not be invoked at runtime. Avoid complexifying function definitions to enable their use with constexpr. Do not use constexpr or consteval to force inlining.

It is important to note that without the `static` keyword, using `constexpr` on local variables can lead to some performance [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509089/610692) with large arrays. They might be initialized at runtime rather than storing them as data in the executable. `constexpr` doesn't [imply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) `static`, only `const`.

A white paper called [Don't constexpr All The Things](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2043r0.pdf) mentions further drawbacks including the complex set of rules necessary to mark a function as `constexpr`.

A pragmatic approach might be to limit the usage of `constexpr` keyword to only compile time functions and variable declarations that support those functions. Marking variables not used in compile time functions as `constexpr` instead of `const` has limited usefulness, unless it can be proven that the compiler will output better assembly.