# Clang static parameter to std::fill causing linker to fail

Tags: c++, static, linker, linker-errors, clang++

Using Clang++ (v3.8.0), the following code fails to link due to `sSomeValue` being an undefined reference.

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    static constexpr int sSomeSize = 3;
    static constexpr int sSomeValue = 10;
};

int foo()
{
    int someArray[MyClass::sSomeSize] = {};
    std::fill(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray), MyClass::sSomeValue);
    return someArray[0];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

More precisely:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

/tmp/main-c8de0c.o: In function `foo()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2): undefined reference to `MyClass::sSomeValue'
/tmp/main-c8de0c.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `MyClass::sSomeValue'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, changing the definition of `foo` to

```
int foo()
{
    int someArray[MyClass::sSomeSize] = {MyClass::sSomeValue, MyClass::sSomeValue, MyClass::sSomeValue};
    return someArray[0];
}
```

does not exhibit the same linker error, even though `sSomeValue` is still being used.

What is going on here? Is the compiler doing some optimization around the `std::fill` call that I may not be aware of?
Note that `g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out` compiles, links, and outputs `10` as expected with v6.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is nothing to do with std::fill.

If you refer below documentation, it says: Reference variables can be declared constexpr (**their initializers have to be reference constant expressions**):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Slight modification of your code works fine. Just make the struct variables "const &" as said above.

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    static constexpr int const& sSomeSize = 3;
    static constexpr int const& sSomeValue = 10;
};

int foo()
{
    int someArray[MyClass::sSomeSize] = {};
    std::fill(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray), MyClass::sSomeValue);
    return someArray[0];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

Also refer here for well explained article about `constexpr`  and `static`
"[Does static constexpr variable make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865842/does-static-constexpr-variable-make-sense)

Specially the last para in ticked answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `constexpr` is relatively new to me, so thank you for pointing out a solution! Still, I'm a little confused why only the `sSomeValue` member complains but `sSomeSize` seems valid to use as the array size parameter.

Also, if the definition of my parameters was `static const int sSomeValue = 10;` I get the same linker error, even though I thought integral types were allowed to be given an initializer list. Can you shine any light on that?

Comment: Look at the definition of std::fill and the last parameter. it expects "const T&" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill

Comment: May be when you declare "static const int sSomeValue = 10;" .. you are still using structure to access it. It is working fine for me with a static declaration "static const int sSomeValue = 10;"

Comment: just call it with out accessing from structure. It should work when you declare "static const int sSomeValue = 10;" . std::fill(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray), sSomeValue);

Comment: A simple example. write a function void bar(int i)
{
    
} and.... call bar(MyClass::sSomeSize)  it works...     Now modify the function to  void bar(int& i)
{} and call  bar(MyClass::sSomeSize). You will understand the difference.

Comment: C++17 fixes this problem. The problem here is that you have not declared any storage for an object, so when you bind to a reference, that object must "exist" somewhere. It is the classic "declare it outside of the class too" issue with C++ statics pre-17.