# C++ in condition

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

How to check if a value is in a on-the-fly created set. I'm looking for some syntactic sugar, like we have in python

```
if s in set(['first','second','third','fourth']):
    print "It's one of first,second,third,fourth";
```

How can it be done efficiently in C++?

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find)?

Comment: sorry, I've just corrected my code to show that I want the most optimal way. I'm looking for something that can be done in one line - in the if.

Comment: @pawel_j Almost anything can be done in one line in c++ if your line is long enough.

Comment: "I want the most optimal way. I'm looking for something that can be done in one line"... one thing has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: std::set::count method is a way to go, if you have rvalue of type set.

Comment: If you want to write as little as possible, why is your Python not `if s in ['first','second','third','fourth']:`?

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
std::string s = "first";
if(std::set<std::string>{"first","second","third","fourth"}.count(s)>=1){
    std::cout << s << " is found" << std::endl;
}
```

BTW, in C++20 and over I think `std::set::contains` is more preferable.

Comment: Why not `unordered_set`?

Comment: @scohe001 For a set of 4 elements, you would have to measure the overheads to see which is better. Even an `std::vector` or `std::array` might be a contender at that number of elements.

Comment: Alternatively, in C++20 `.contains(s)` can be used.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux meh fair enough.

Comment: count() will iterate over all elements, and is not an optimization. More like @HolyBlackCat 's solution - contains() is an optimization - but not present before C++20 (that's why I asked question, because using .find() is not possible in one liner, as you need to use the reference to the set twice).

Comment: @pawel_j `count()` will not iterate over all elements. For plain `std::set` (as opposed to `std::multiset`) it's no different from `.contains()` (except one looks prettier than the other).

Comment: @pawel_j Thx for your performance testing. Yes, initial rebalance of `std::set` is usually expensive. And now I understand you want *really* high performance syntax sugar.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this to be efficient then you are not going to want to construct a container just to check if the value exists.  What we can do is leverage C++17's [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and write a function like

```
template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<const char*, Args>...>, bool> = true>
bool string_exists(std::string to_find, Args... args)
{
    return ((to_find == args) || ...);
}
```

which then lets you write the if statement like

```
int main()
{
    std::string element;
    // get value of element somehow
    if (string_exists(element, "1", "2", "3", "4"))
        std::cout << "found";
}
```

And now no container and no `std::string` objects are created. If you want to accept string objects you could change the functions to

```
template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<const char*, Args>...> ||
                                            std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<std::string, Args>...>, bool> = true>
bool string_exists(std::string to_find, Args... args)
{
    return ((to_find == args) || ...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string element;
    // get value of element somehow
    if (string_exists(element, some, other, string, variables))
        std::cout << "found";
}
```

---

Do note that the last example doesn't allow you to mix string literals with `std::string`'s.

Comment: That's quite a good solution with the template folding, but not really an optimization when the number of the possible values is larger, providing that set was created once and later reused. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

I do not see anything wrong in using `find` method

```
std::set<std::string>aset {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"}; 
std::string s = "third";

if(aset.find(s) != aset.end()){
    std::cout << "It's one of first,second,third,fourth";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

void foo(const std::string& s) {
    if (std::unordered_set<std::string>{"1", "2", "3", "4"}.count(s) != 0) {
        std::cout << "It's one of 1,2,3,4\n";
    }
}
```

In C++17 you can let deduction guides come into play to clean up the template argument (note that I need to use `std::string` literals to avoid deducing as `const char*`):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
if (std::unordered_set{"1"s, "2"s, "3"s, "4"s}.count(s) != 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can it be done efficiently in C++? [...] I'm looking for something that can be done in one line - in the if

In "one line - in the if" and "efficiently" are different things.

If you really want all in a line, I suggest the 0x5453's solution (also the Hiroki's one) that uses count.

I propose an alternative based on `emplace()` (but works also with `insert()`)

```
if ( ! std::set<std::string>{"first", "second", "third", "fourth"}.emplace(s).second )
   std::cout << "It's one of first,second,third,fourth" << std::endl;
```

but I don't think it's very efficiently: think if you use it in a loop: every time you have to create a set and insert a new element; so you have to recreate the same set and insert another element.

It's better the solution based on `count()` but just because the compiler can optimize the code avoiding to recreate the set every time.

If you want efficiency, I suggest the haccks's solution (making also `const` the set, but I suspect that the compiler optimize anyway)

```
 std::set<std::string> const numSet {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"}; 

 if ( numSet.find(s) != numSet.cend() )
    std::cout << "It's one of first,second,third,fourth" << std::endl;
```

or, better, avoid the `std::set` at all ad check using template folding, as suggested by NathanOliver (you need C++17 but, maybe loosing short circuiting, isn't really difficult adapt it in C++14).

Comment: yes, definitely one line is not optimal, as the set will be recreated every time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to check your solutions, using a benchmarking tool to see the outcomes. It seems that creating a set in-situ is a performance killer, that's why one should avoid such solution, which is otherwise quite fast in python (need to do performance tests in python too).

So, when using a pre-created set it's almost twice as fast as using multiple ifs. Test done for number of items = 10.

[image]

For items = 4, set is only 18% faster than multiple ifs.
[image]

When creating the set in every if, the set code is almost 900% slower.

[image]

Link to the benchmark http://quick-bench.com/iqQJWxaRgQGh4Sry2YtfxdSqTio (but it might disappear so I also add the code tested

```
static void withSet(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::vector<std::string> l = {"1","2","9","10"};
  int i = 0;
  std::set<std::string> s = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};

  for (auto _ : state) {
    const std::string t = l[i++%l.size()];
    if (s.find(t) != s.end() ) {
      benchmark::DoNotOptimize(t);
    }
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(withSet);

static void withIfs(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::vector<std::string> l = {"1","2","9","10"};
  int i = 0;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    const std::string t = l[i++%l.size()];
    if (t == "1" || t == "2" || t == "3" || t == "4" ||
    t == "5" || t == "6" || t == "7" || t == "8" ||
    t == "9" || t == "10"
    ) {
      benchmark::DoNotOptimize(t);
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(withIfs);
```

--- edit ---

Additionaly I understood that count() in set is not equal iterating every element in set. This is the outcome of benchmark between find() != end() and count()

[image]

Comment: If you need to do it fast, consider using a pre-sorted `std::vector` with `std::binary_search`.

Answer (score 0):

I post an alternative approach which is not a true one liner but shows good performance as tested bellow.
The basic idea is same with @NathanOliver.
The idea is initializing a data set `{"first", ..., "fourth"}` at a compile-time with [**`static constexpr`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865842/does-static-constexpr-variable-make-sense) qualifier to get a run-time performance gain:

- In C++17 and over, `std::string_view` is available and this has `constexpr` ctors.
  Thus it is natural to apply `static constexpr std::array` of `std::string_view` to improve the performance.
- In addition, for such a small size data set ~10, naive linear search with cache locality of contiguous arrays sometimes beat other algorithms.
  So I deliberately use `std::find` here.

This is easily done using C++17's *if statement with initializer* as follows:

```
if(static constexpr 
   std::array<std::string_view, 4>
   v = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"};
   std::find(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), s) != v.cend())
```

This can be summarized as the following compact and portable syntax sugar macro:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>

#define IF_CONTAINS(str, ...)                                          \
if(static constexpr                                                    \
   std::array<                                                         \
       std::string_view,                                               \
       std::tuple_size<decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__))>::value> \
   v = {__VA_ARGS__};                                                  \
   std::find(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), str) != v.cend())
```

This macro `IF_CONTAINS` works fine as if-statement as follows:

[**Live DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DcFyW1WpEFRmx8pM)

```
std::string s = "first";

IF_CONTAINS(s, "first", "second", "third", "fourth") {
    std::cout << s << " is found" << std::endl;
}
```

---

**Performance Test 1**

First, we test the performance of this approach with the above data set `{"first", "second", "third", "fourth"}`.
Tests are done with Quick C++ Benchmark, *gcc-8.2, C++17 and O3 optimization*.
The results are as follows:

- `const std::string s = "first";` ([**Live DEMO**](http://quick-bench.com/mS-NA95N58TCR5XCsWiYA5dHMoM))

  1.1 times slower than naive implementation.

[image]

- `const std::string s = "second";` ([**Live DEMO**](http://quick-bench.com/Ggfp0oPjZNeIeSwMcH_4njGEunM))

  3.7 times faster than naive implementation.

[image]

- `const std::string s = "third";` ([**Live DEMO**](http://quick-bench.com/0Ahi4bWr_kfyAgCypfZJ5t98Qqw))

  1.9 times faster than naive implementation.

[image]

- `const std::string s = "fourth";` ([**Live DEMO**](http://quick-bench.com/l7vPPgm88CiEsQMoSRLgWnXx9x8))

  3.1 times faster than naive implementation.

[image]

---

**Performance Test 2**

Finally, we test the performance with a data set `{"1", ...,"10"}`.
The test code is same with @pawel_j 's one.
This test shows 2.7 times faster result than naive implementation:

[**Live DEMO**](http://quick-bench.com/iEOnxOirHLQEtViuk8SHqlYlQRE)

[image]